# How to get box using routeBoxer using Google Direction apis in php?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, routeboxer

I am trying to get overview_path in google direction api, but it not appearing in the response.

When i am using js sdk , I am getting the overview_path array in routes array but when I tried calling the direction api in postman, overview_path array is missing in the routes array. 
Here is the url of postman.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood4&key=please_add_your_key&alternatives=true&units=metric&mode=driving
```

I am trying to   get boxes for my path using routeBoxer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is overview_polyline which is encoded version of the overview_path, you need to decode it and you will get lat, lng of it.
http://unitstep.net/blog/2008/08/02/decoding-google-maps-encoded-polylines-using-php/